How to determine the continent name by a country code in Swift
I have an ISO two-letter country code (e.g., "US") and need to determine its continent's name.
I know about the continent property of Locale.Region, which is also a Locale.Region instance, but it doesn't have a name, only a BCP 47 identifier.

To get a localised name of a region, Locale has method localizedString(forRegionCode:).
So, the first step is to obtain the continent's ID:
let continentID = Locale.Region(stringLiteral: countryCode).continent?.identifier

Then Locale will tell you its localised name:
let continentName = Locale.current.localizedString(forRegionCode: continentID)


how does it work for countries that span multiple continents , such as Turkey, Egypt or Russia?

Good question. I tried it, and got this: "TR" -> "Asia," "EG" -> "Africa," "RU" -> "Europe." From docs, it's not clear how exactly API determines it.

I don’t there’s any rules to determine it by, it has just been decided for some geographical, political or historical reason what continent a country belongs to if it spans more than one continent
